# php sql form submit on same page, but sql loads too early to give error

Tags: php, mysql

okay i  have this first form which is used to get the input text and supposed to send them to sql table

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
<input type="text" placeholder="ask your question!"  class="assin assin-success assin-autosize" name="post_question">
<input type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

and then i  have this php below it

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `as_questions`(`Qid`, `M_class`, `S_class`, `Question`, `Answer`, `Doctor`, `Time`) VALUES
('n','n','n','$_POST[post_question]','a','d',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");?>
```

it works once i enter a question and submit, but when i first load the page, the  php query seems to run and give : Undefined index: post_question, because on load it is empty? and the query runs. how do i fix this?

Comment: Check that the form was submitted. See `empty` or `isset`. Also you are open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) OR [!empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

```
if(isset($_POST['post_question'])){
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
   mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `as_questions`(`Qid`, `M_class`, `S_class`, `Question`, `Answer`, `Doctor`, `Time`) VALUES
   ('n','n','n','$_POST[post_question]','a','d',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks :) how do i prevent double entry into database when i reload?

Comment: You need to write a SELECT query just before insert and check if record is exist then you do not need to reinsert it. Let me know if you will face any problem to doing that. All the best :)